# Extension of a measure defined in a filtration to the whole space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $(\Omega,\left(\mathcal F_t\right)_{t\geq 0},\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a filterated probability space fulfiling the usual measurability conditions (see  "Diffusions, Markov processes and martingales - Roger and Williams" Definition II.67.1). If needed it can be assumed that:

- $\Omega := \mathcal C_0^0(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)=\{\omega:\mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R;\ \omega\ \text{is continuous and }\omega(0) =0\}.$
- $\mathcal F_{t} = \sigma\left(W_s; 0\leq s\leq t\right),$ where $W_s$ is the standard Brownian motion.
- $\mathcal F = \sigma(W_s; s\geq 0),$
- $\mathbb P$ the Wiener measure.

Let $\{M_s:\Omega \to \mathbb R_+\}_{s\geq 0},$ be a martingale with respect to the filtration $\{\mathcal F_s\}_{s\geq 0},$ satisfying $\mathbb E[M_s] = 1.$

Consider the measure  $\mathbb Q_s$ on $\mathcal F_s$ defined as $$\mathbb Q_s[A] = \mathbb E[\mathbb 1_A M_s] \ \text{for every }s\geq 0\ \text{and }A\in\mathcal F_s.$$

> My question: Is it possible to guarantee that there exists a measure $\mathbb Q_\infty$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F),$ such that
> $$ \mathbb Q_\infty (A_s) = \mathbb Q_s [A_s], \ \text{for every }A_s\in\mathcal F_s?$$

I do not know if this is true. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you can show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}M_t$ exists (this might be a problem...) almost surely you can let $M_\infty$ be the random variable which is equal to this limit when it exists and $0$ otherwise. Then define $\mathbb{Q}_\infty(A):=\mathbb{E}[1_A M_\infty]$. You'll want to use that $\mathbb{Q}_t(A_s)=\mathbb{Q}_s(A_s)$ for all $t\geq s$ and $A_s\in\mathcal{F}_s$.

Comment: Theorems V.4.1 and V.4.2 in the book K.R. Parthasarathy, *Probability Measures on Metric Spaces*, Academic Press NY 1967, provide conditions under which the measure $\mathbb Q_\infty$ exists. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the reference. I am not sure how to apply these theorems because it seems (in the case of the Wiener space) that $(\Omega,\mathcal F_t)$ will not be a standard metric Borel space. Please, tell me if I am missing something

Comment: @MatheusManzatto . Unfortunately, Parthasarathy is a bit short on examples. I think that according to H. Bauer, *Probability Theory*, Thm. 38.6 your space $(\Omega,{\cal F})$ is a standard Borel space. Do you think that the sigma algebra ${\cal F}_t$ is isomorphic to the Borel sigma algebra of ${\cal C}_0^0( [0,t], \mathbb R)$ ? Then $(\Omega,{\cal F}_t)$ should also be a standard Borel space. Karatzas & Shreve write on p. 192 of *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* that the measure $\mathbb Q_\infty$ exists and refer to Parthasarathy for details.